# How to use diff function in R to produce monthly boxplot of returns

Tags: r, diff

I'm trying to make monthly box plot and everything else is working but the diff function in R. I'm trying to calculate the returns. Rstudio is giving me Error :replacement has [x] rows, data has [y].

The data is ^GDAXI from yahoo finance

```
stocks$Returns <- diff(stocks[,"Returns"],lag=1): "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Returns, value = c(-0.024564607951433,  : replacement has 5093 rows, data has 5094"

stocks <- read.csv("^GDAXI.csv")
stocks[,1] <- as.Date(stocks[,1])
stocks <- na.omit(stocks)

stocks$Returns <- log(stocks[,"Close"])
stocks$Returns <- diff(stocks[,"Returns"],lag=1)

stocks$Month <- factor(format(stocks$Date, "%m"))
ggplot(stocks, aes(Month, Returns)) + geom_boxplot() + stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') + ggtitle("Boxplot of Returns")
```

With new xts file I don't have errors but the boxplot stopped working

```
stocks <- read.csv("^GDAXI.csv")
stocks[,1] <- as.Date(stocks[,1])
stocks <- xts(stocks[, -1], order.by=as.Date(stocks$Date))
stocks <- stocks[,-1]
stocks <- na.omit(stocks)
stocks <- stocks[complete.cases(stocks), ]


stocks_ret <- diff(log(stocks[,3]))
stocks_ret <- stocks_ret[-1,]
stocks_ret$Month <- factor(format(index(stocks_ret), "%m"))


ggplot(stocks_ret, aes(Month, Close, group =1)) + geom_boxplot() + stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') + ggtitle("Boxplot of Returns")
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the number of differences is one less than the number of values. You can get around that by repeating the first value (will make return for the first month be zero).

```
stocks$Returns <- diff(c(stocks[1,"Returns"], stocks[,"Returns"]), lag=1)
```